# Using Notepad++ to view text files that also contain lower ASCII control characters

Tags: notepad++, text-editors, text-editing, ascii

When using Notepad++ to view text files that also contain some lower ASCII control characters (such as `NUL`, `BEL`, and `ACK`), it shows every lower ASCII character in brackets like this:

`[NUL][BEL][ACK]`

Is it possible to have it automatically replace lower (non-displayable) ASCII characters as blank spaces, or simply strip them out?

***Update:*** What I'm after is to use Notepad++ as a tool to view the visible ASCII (or Unicode) characters any file.  It's fast and can load files of almost any size.  When I have a file of unknown contents, it's rather ideal.  With it's extensive language formatting, if the file is of a recognizable language, it will format it perfectly.  If it's plain text, it will show it perfectly.  The challenge comes in when a file has plain text mixed with lower ASCII characters.  The automatic conversion of all those characters to the `[XYZ]` format makes viewing the file very difficult.  I'm looking for a way to avoid that automatic conversion so the files are easier to view.

Comment: Replace in the target file, or only when viewing?

Comment: @Arjan Great question.  Only when viewing, although I'm fine if it changes the target file as well.

Comment: I thought they were called control characters.

Comment: @jiggunjer Yes, that is correct.  People often call them *control characters*, *low ASCII characters*, *non-displayable characters*, *non-printing characters*, *signaling characters*, and other similar terms.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the RegEx pattern:

```
[\x00-\x1F]+
```

To remove all low ASCII chars:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  That's very useful.  Is there any sort of filter or language setting that will do that automatically?

Comment: @RockPaperLizard hmmm, not that springs to mind I'm afraid. Perhaps combining it with a macro and NppExec? Not at my machine to test at the moment though, sorry!