# Powershell String Concatenation puts strings at random

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, powershell

I am facing some very weird behavior with my Powershell script. I am getting values from a pdf document via Word as a ComObject. Getting the values works fine and is no problem, but as soon as I try to concatenate two variables I got from the document, after concatenating them one of them is missing. At first I suspected it was a problem with the underscore, but after trying out every possible form of escaping, such as `_ or ${variable}_ and even substituting it with another characters such as a space, I still have the same problem.

I can display the variables by themselves and they return the right value, but after concatenation I get some very weird behavior.

`$filepath = "C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\all_spools\"
    $wd = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
    $wd.Visible = $false
    $files = Get-ChildItem -path $filepath
    foreach($file in $files) {
    $doc = $wd.Documents.Open($file.FullName)
        if ($doc.tables(1).rows.count -eq 7) {
            $docnum = $doc.tables(1).Columns(2).cells(2).Range.Text
            $intdocarr = $doc.tables(1).Columns(2).cells(7).Range.Text
            $intdocnum = $intdocarr.split(" ")
            $finalintdocnum = $intdocnum | Select-Object -first 1
            $doc.Close()
        }
        else {
            $docnum = $doc.tables(1).Columns(2).cells(2).Range.Text
            $intdocarr = $doc.tables(1).Columns(2).cells(8).Range.Text
            $intdocnum = $intdocarr.split(" ")
            $finalintdocnum = $intdocnum | Select-Object -first 1
            $doc.Close()
        }
   $filename = "${docnum}_$finalintdocnum.pdf"
    $filename
   }
   $wd.Quit()`

My expected output would be something like "90004234_74503423.pdf", but infact I get "_74503424.pdf". Sometimes at random it becomes "_74503423.pdf90004234", which is not reproducible. I am kind of lost.

When the variable $docnum is used to rename the file, I get an error with illegal charaters in path, I have also tried stripping everything and regexing out only numbers.

My question is, am I missing something? I cannot figure out why this would not work.

Comment: Probably your `$doc.tables(1).Columns(2).cells(2).Range.Text` contains garbage.

Comment: I'd use `$finalintdocnum = $intdocarr.Split(" ")[0]` but otherwise without **your** data it's difficult to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pipe `$doc.tables(1).Columns(2).cells(2).Range.Text` to `clip` and paste into a more revealing text editor (I'm using Notepad++), you'll see that an ascii character is captured that you're not expecting.

[image]

You can change the declaration of `$docnum` by [excluding these characters](https://superuser.com/questions/1036388/using-notepad-to-view-text-files-that-also-contain-lower-ascii-control-charact), in both your `if` and `else`.

```
$docnum = ($doc.tables(1).Columns(2).cells(2).Range.Text) -replace "[\x00-\x1F]+"
```

Also, you should set `$filename` like this. The way you have it, the underscore is treated as part of the variable name.

```
$filename = "$docnum" + "_" + "$finalintdocnum.pdf"
```

Comment: Thank you, that was what I suspected as well, the trick with clip is very handy. You really helped me out